# How do i prove there are only 8 elements of order 3 in $S_4$ and they are all in $A_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How do i prove there are only 8 elements of order 3 in $S_4$ and they are all in $A_4$?

Should i prove this by considering all 24 cases?

Comment: They are all in $A_4$ by definition, since their order (3) is odd.

Comment: Consider the $3$-cycles.

Comment: No, you need not consider all cases.Any element of order 3 is a 3-cycle.Why?  In how many ways can you choose a 3-cycle? Does a 3-cycle belong to $A_4$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's a much easier way. First note that of the cycle types present in $S_4$, only one is of order three, namely the $3$-cycle. Now you only need to count the number of $3$-cycles in $S_4$. To do this, we note that a $3$-cycle is determined by picking $3$ distinct numbers in $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and ordering them. There are $24$ ways to do this. Of course, each ordering can be cycled through three equivalent orderings, so we have overcounted by a factor of $3$. Thus, there are $8$ distinct $3$-cycles in $S_4$.

Finally, these are all in $A_4$ since any $3$-cycle is an even permutation.

Comment: You gave out a lot of information!

Comment: @Manasi The answer is OK

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary permutation $\pi \in S_4$ and break it into a product of disjoint cycles. That is, $\pi = \tau_1 \circ \tau_2 \circ \cdot \cdot \cdot \circ \tau_n$. This can always be done.

In the decomposition above, suppose that $\tau_1$ is a $k_1$-cycle, $\tau_2$ is a $k_2$-cycle, and so forth.  Then prove to yourself that the following holds:

$$|\pi| = lcm(|k_1|, |k_2|, ..., |k_n|)$$

Once you have this result, then all that remains is recognizing that $|\pi| = 3$ $\iff$ $\pi$ decomposes as a single $3$-cycle.  And lastly, any $n$-cycle is an even permutation $\iff$ $n$ is odd.

Knowing the above information, it suffices to simply count the number of $3$-cycles in $S_4$.